# Unit Test a Service using Angular 6 HttpTestingController

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, http, jasmine

I have a Angular v6 service that calls a .net core API and receives a blob which is a PDF.  When it receives a OK response from the API the service also sets a flag to true, which is used by a component.

I'm trying to write a Jasmine unit test for this behavior, and it keeps reporting the flag is false (but does prompt me to download the fake file). Karma reports: `Expected undefined to be truthy.`  When using the deployed code everything looks to be working properly, so I think its a mistake in the Unit Test.

This is my first Angular 6 app and use of Typescript, so it might be the mistake is some thing simpler.

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { InputParameters } from './inputParameters';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettlementService
{
    success: boolean;
    private apiUrl = environment.apiURL;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getSettlement(inputParms: InputParameters, captchaResponse: string)
    {
        //add captcha response header
        let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('g-recaptcha-response', captchaResponse);

        //submit post request to service layer
        return this.http
            .post(this.apiUrl, inputParms, { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response', headers: headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response =>
            {
                this.success = true;
                this.saveToFileSystem(response);
            })
            .catch((reason: Response) =>
            {
                this.success = false;
                console.log(reason);
                //alert("Settlement not found!");
            });
    }

    private saveToFileSystem(response)
    {
        //get the file name from the content-disposition header
        const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
        const fileName = parts[1].split('=')[1];

        const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        saveAs(blob, fileName);
    }
}
```

The unit test of the service I'm testing:

```
import { TestBed, inject, getTestBed, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { SettlementService } from './settlement.service';
import { InputParameters } from './inputParameters';

describe('SettlementService', () =>
{
    let injector: TestBed;
    let service: SettlementService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() =>
    {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [SettlementService]
        });

        injector = getTestBed();
        service = injector.get(SettlementService);
        httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    afterEach(() =>
    {
        httpMock.verify();
    });

    it('should download a file and success should be true', (() =>
    {
        //arrange
        //return blob
        const file = new Blob(['ATESTFILE'], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        //setup input parms
        let parms: InputParameters = new InputParameters();
        parms.agreementNumber = '001234567898';
        parms.bankAccountNumber = '00112233';
        var date: Date = new Date();
        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 20);
        parms.dateOfBirth = date;

        //act
        service.getSettlement(parms, '0000000');

        //assert
        expect(service.success).toBeTruthy();

        const req = httpMock
            .expectOne('http://localhost:5000/api/settlement');
        expect(req.request.headers.has('g-recaptcha-response'));
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');

        //act
        req.flush(file, {
            headers: { 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="testfilename.pdf"' },
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK'
        });
    }));
```

Comment: Post the output of the error you're getting. The test looks good.

Comment: added it to the q, but its `Expected undefined to be truthy.`

Comment: I'm thinking you need to wait for the service to resolve the `.then` block before asserting `success` is truthy. Since the method returns a promise you may just be able to use: `await service.getSettlement(parms, '0000000');` but to use `await` you will need to add `async`, so the `it` description becomes: `it('should download a file and success should be true', async (() =>`

Comment: That's changed the failure to: `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` and then `Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: POST http://localhost:5000/api/settlement` which i guess is from the `afterEach` block.

Comment: You need to subscribe to your service.getSettlement(...) and within that subscribe you  can verify your expect(service.success).toBeTruthy(). As cjb100 mentioned, you are verifying the success property before the request is being made.